# textview alignment in linearlayout (wrong margin and padding)

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to use a TextView horizontally aligned to a following EditText inside a LinearLayout. Unfortunately it looks (to me) that the Parent LinearLayout adds more space than defined by XML. This happens only, when I use both Views together. If I use 2 EditText oder Buttons the I can't see any issues.

E.g. Top is my result, bottom the expected

IMAGE: compare.gif

When I remove that EditText, it looks like expected:

IMAGE: compare2.gif

Images: 
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B4ipfo7vG5R9N0hBZm1iLUFIV2c&usp=sharing

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:background="#ccc"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:background="#ff0000"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_name"

        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:hint="@string/label_category"
        android:maxLength="64"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

I'm using Android Studio 0.5.1

Is there anything I have overlooked? Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the LinearLayout add: `android:gravity="center_vertical"`

Answer (score 0):

`layout_width` parameter in `EditText` should be :

```
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

and further use `layout_weight` for space distribution between `TextView` and `EditText`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `android:gravity="center"` to the `LinearLayout`.

You could also try adding `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"` to the two `View`s themselves.

If you're still having trouble then you can check out this blog post, which talks about laying out views exactly like this:
http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/14/how-to-position-views-properly-in-layouts/

Comment: android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" did the trick (but it's still a hack :-)). Thanks! But I still do not understand WHY this is happening to the TextView, if other views (Buttons, EditTexts, etc) shows not such behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:background="#ccc"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Test"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:background="#ff0000"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_name"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/label_category"
        android:maxLength="64"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Use this instead and see if it fulfills your need ...

thx

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way, hope this will help you...
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="#ccc"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_height="48dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:background="#ff0000"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_name"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="@string/label_category"
        android:maxLength="64"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code text view aligned horizontally with edit text fix for all screen .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ccc"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:gravity="center"
     >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight=".2"
        android:background="#ff0000" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".8"
        android:hint="@string/label_category"
        android:maxLength="64"
        android:singleLine="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```